# Angular inline resources in css as data-uri

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-4, angular-builder

Is there any way in Angular app without ejecting webpack configuration to have inlined resources, as SVGs in CSS background properties?

I have already tried custom webpack builder to remove built-in file-loader rule and add uri-loader, but, SVGs are not inlined.

I suspect that it may be somehow related to internal SCSS/CSS processing using postcss.

Comment: you could try ngStyle ... however most of the time you will need to run Sanitizer on the data: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer here is another question that should be similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991613/angular-how-do-i-sanitize-a-style-inside-a-plain-typescript-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, `url-loader` does not handle urls in style files. To do that, you need to use [`postcss-url` package](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-url).

To use a custom webpack configuration without ejecting, you need to install [this package](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders). After configuring your workspace with the directions provided in that package, you can use the following webpack configuration:

```js
const url = require('postcss-url');    
const urlPlugin = url([{ filter: '**/*.svg', url: 'inline' }]);
    
module.exports = config => {
  for (const rule of config.module.rules) {
      const loader = rule.use && rule.use.find(x => x.loader === 'postcss-loader');
      if (loader) {
          loader.options.plugins = [urlPlugin];
      }
  }
    
  return config;
};
```

Basically, this code adds `postcss-url` plugin to every `postcss-loader` in Angular's default webpack configuration.

You can edit this configuration to customize for your needs. For example, you can use `maxSize` parameter to exclude files greater than a certain size. Read [`postcss-url` repo](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-url) for all options.

**EDIT by Zygimantas:**

I am accepting your answer as correct and adding a Typescript version of webpack.config.ts

```js
import { Configuration, NewLoader } from 'webpack'
import * as PostCssUrlPlugin from 'postcss-url'

export default (config: Configuration) => {
    if (config.module === undefined) {
        throw new Error()
    }

    let patched = false
    for (const rule of config.module.rules) {
        if ('use' in rule && Array.isArray(rule.use)) {
            const loader = rule.use.find(
                (a): a is NewLoader =>
                    typeof a !== 'string' &&
                    'options' in a &&
                    a.loader !== undefined &&
                    a.loader.includes('postcss-loader'),
            )

            if (loader !== undefined && loader.options !== undefined) {
                loader.options.plugins = [PostCssUrlPlugin([{
                  filter: '**/*.svg',
                  url: 'inline',
                }])]

                patched = true
            }
        }
    }

    if (!patched) {
        throw new Error('Could not patch webpack configuration')
    }

    return config
}
```

**NOTE:**

In Javascript version, I had to use `x.loader.includes('postcss-loader')` instead of `x.loader === 'postcss-loader'` because `loader` value was a full path in my case.

Comment: I will be able to award a bounty in 17 hours since now.

Comment: @Zygimantas thanks for the edit. By the way, Angular may change their webpack configuration from version to version, so watch out for that. My original answer was for Angular 8.